# how to auto add multiple youtube video id to jw player and play them sequentially?

Tags: php, youtube

This is I would like to achieve.  Post multiple youtube ids in wordpress post, something like this "3jSDiJ, DJIJWk, JDIJAs" and I would like to load them into to jw player and play them sequentially.

first I need to able to detect how many ',' are there so that in jw player code i can create a loop to create multiple of

```
     { 
           'file': 'http://www.youtube.com/v?3jSDiJ', 

      }
```

this is an example of two videos

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   jwplayer("container").setup({
    'flashplayer': 'jwplayer.swf',
    'playlist': [{
        'file': 'http://www.youtube.com/v?3jSDiJ', 

     },{ 
        'file': 'http://www.youtube.cmo/v?3jSDiJ', 

     }],
     repeat: 'list'
     });
   </script>
```

your suggestion and help are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really given enough info to tell for sure, but assuming that the Youtube IDs are being stored in an array, you could do something like this -

```
$youtubeids=array('3jSDiJ', 'DJIJWk', 'JDIJAs');
foreach ($youtubeids as $youtubeid) {
    echo "'file': 'http://www.youtube.cmo/v?".$youtubeid.",";
}
```

Just put this code so that it prints the output within your javascript.